# How can I conditionally run a suite of tests based on iOS device?

Tags: ios, unit-testing

I have a fairly comprehensive suite of tests, but a couple of classes are only used on iPhone. I'd like to exclude these tests when my test target is iPad / iPad simulator.

What would be the best way to achieve this with a Universal Binary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy with Specta or Kiwi:

```
SpecBegin(SQFPhoneViewController)

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

  describe(@"SQFPhoneViewController", ^{
    // Tests to only be run on iPhone
  }

SpecEnd
```